# Macro triggered upon change, moving information based on date

Tags: android

Have a large workbook with sheets for each month.  The main page is where I have managers paste information from another report.  What I'm looking to do is write a VBA macro that automatically triggers each time information is pasted into the particular cells (triggered upon change) of the input worksheet.  In addition, I'd like the macro to then take the accounts with October dates and cut/paste them into the October sheet, etc., for every month.  Please help